# I don't know how to list the real users

Tags: ubuntu

I have a problem in listing all the real users. A real user is a user with a valid login shell. I know that the valid shells are found in etc/shells but i don't know how to list just the users that have a valid login shell. How should the command look? I forgot to tell that i need them listed in lexicographic order, one on a row. I should make a bash script with that commands. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what you want is here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-users-command/

Comment: thank you. i saw that site but i don't understand what exactly to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your non-system uid should be lesser than 1000 you can run the following command, that filters uids by that field, and displays only the username:

```
awk -F: '($3>=1000)&&($1!="nobody"){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

If you want all the user info just remove the last part

```
awk -F: '($3>=1000)&&($1!="nobody")' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. the only problem was that the root would not be listed but i resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Search the command interpreter field (the last field) of the passwd file for any user shell ending in "sh" e.g. (sh, csh, ksh, bash, dash, fish). `$NF` is the last field.

Non-login users such as man and games have a command interpreter of `/usr/sbin/nologin`. Daemons' shell field is set to `/bin/false`.

Finally, pipe the user list to `sort`.

```
awk -F: '$NF ~ /sh$/' {print $1} /etc/passwd | sort
```

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful.